# Copying the docstring of function onto another function by name

Tags: python, docstring

I'm looking to copy the docstring of a function in the same file by name (with a decorator).

I can easily do it with a function that is out of the current module, but I'm a bit confused when it comes to the same module (or the same class more specifically)

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import inspect

def copy_doc(func_name: str):
    def wrapper(func):
        doc = ... # get doc from function that has the name as func_name
        func.__doc__ = doc
        return func
    retun wrapper
```

I'm looking for something that can do two of these examples:

Ex 1:

```py
def this() -> None:
    """Fun doc string"""
    return

@copy_doc('this')
def that() -> None:
    return

print(that.__doc__)
```

Ex 2:

```py
class This:
    def foo(self) -> None:
        """Fun doc string"""
        return None

    @copy_doc('foo')
    def bar(self) -> None:
        return None

print(This().bar.__doc__)
```

Any fun ideas?

Comment: You can replace @copy_doc('this') with @copy_doc(this) and try func_name.__doc__

Comment: That's true, yes. Still need the second example covered tho, that's the important one :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some testing and experimentation, I learned you could directly reference the function in a given class.

* Note [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) and [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) are to keep the correct signature of the wrapped function, you can remove all the annotations if you do not need them.

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Any, TypeAlias
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')
WrappedFuncDeco: TypeAlias = Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]


def copy_doc(copy_func: Callable[..., Any]) -> WrappedFuncDeco[P, T]:
    """Copies the doc string of the given function to another. 
    This function is intended to be used as a decorator.

    .. code-block:: python3

        def foo():
            '''This is a foo doc string'''
            ...

        @copy_doc(foo)
        def bar():
            ...
    """

    def wrapped(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        func.__doc__ = copy_func.__doc__
        return func

    return wrapped


class Cas:
    def foo(self) -> None:
        """This is the foo doc string."""
        return

    @copy_doc(foo)
    def bar(self) -> None:
        return


print(Cas.bar.__doc__)
# >>> This is the foo doc string.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expansion of Iced Chai's answer that will also copy over the function signature as well:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

def wraps(wrapper: Callable[P, T]):
    """An implementation of functools.wraps."""

    def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable[P, T]:
        func.__doc__ = wrapper.__doc__
        return func

    return decorator
```

Please note that on Python version <= 3.9 `ParamSpec` is imported from `typing_extensions` instead from `typing`. If you need cross version compatibility you can import like this:

```py
import sys
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
if sys.version_info <= (3, 9):
    from typing_extensions import ParamSpec
else:
    from typing import ParamSpec
```

Example usage

```py
def func(x: int, y: int) -> str:
    """I have a docstring and arguments"""

@wraps(func)
def anotherfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Your IDE intellisense/autocomplete should suggest/preview the signature and docstring of `func` when typing `anotherfunc()`. I tested this on VSCode and it worked for me. I often use this approach instead of importing `functools.wraps` because `functools.wraps` doesn't seem to copying the function signature for VSCode's intellisense.

On VSCode when I type `anotherfunc()` the intellisense suggestion popup shows:

```
(x: int, y: int) -> str
-------------------------
I have a docstring
```

Here is why it works for anyone curious:

`Callable[P, T]` essentially means "A function that takes in *P* parameters and returns a type *T*". `ParamSpec` reserves not just the argument types, but also their names, order, defaults, and whether they are positional arguments or keyword arguments. Typing two variables with `Callable[P, T] *within some common scope* is the same as saying "Both of these functions take the same arguments and return the same type"

Here we type hint both the `wrapper` parameter of `wraps` and the return type of `decorator` with `Callable[P, T]`. This tells editor's static type checker that the resulting function from decoration has the same signature as the input parameter of the `wraps` function.

More concretely, using the example above, we're saying that the signature of the resulting function from decorating `anotherfunc` has the same signature as `func`.

Resources:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar