# Best practice for type annotation and docstring inheritance

Tags: python, docstring

I have a python class like this

```py
class LinBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            inp_features: int,
            out_features: int,
            activation: Callable[[], "nn.Module"] = None,
            normalizer: Callable[[int], "nn.Module"] = None,
            n: int = 1,
            p: float = 0,
            activation_every_n: bool = False,
            normalizer_every_n: bool = True,
            sample_type: Literal["mono", "bi"] = "mono",
            **extras,
    ):
        """
        :param inp_features: number of input features
        :param out_features: number of output features
        :param activation: activation function
        :param normalizer: normalization layer
        :param n: number of intermediate convolutions
        :param p: dropout probability
        :param activation_every_n: whether to apply activation after every n convolutions
        :param normalizer_every_n: whether to apply normalizer after every n convolutions
        :param sample_type: type of sampling, either mono or bi
        :param extras: arguments to pass to the linear layers
        """
        ...
```

which is inherited like this

```py
class ResidualLinBlock(LinBlock):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        # other stuff goes here, specific to `ResidualLinBlock`
```

this creates a problem in code editors like PyCharm which does not understand that `ResidualLinBlock` (*args, **kwargs) has the same signature as `LinBlock` and thus does not show the doc string hints

What would be the best practice in python for such scenarios

Comment: Do not add another `__init__` method in the subclass just to call the parent's one. It is not required to be there, the parent's one will be called when the child's one is missing.

Comment: I wonder, would  `@functools.wraps(LinBlock.__init__)` work? Or you could `__init__.__doc__ = LinBlock.__doc__` somewhere, not sure where. Also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68901049/copying-the-docstring-of-function-onto-another-function-by-name .

Comment: Since the signature does not change in the subclass, consider whether the "other stuff" really does need to be in the `__init__` method (cannot be moved elsewhere), falsely justifying its existence. Also, these are not my downvotes.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried the .__doc__ way, does not seem to work, cause PyCharm checks for statically generated docs. maybe it's an IDE thing?

Comment: @Jeyekomon this is just an example, the parent class is being used in several ways, in general, a `class A` having n args and m kwargs with associated docs, can it be inherited by children with a different initialization, but same/extra params instead of rewriting all of it.


class A does some common initializations and have abstract and common methods which can be inherited by a lot of other children which does its own initializations